# Requirement to create conditional auto number field for Account number

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement to create a auto number field for Account number in Account object.

The number will start from 10000 then 10001 upto 20000.After that The number will start from A0000 and will go on till Z0000.After that it will stop creating any new accounts and throw an error "account has reached to its maximum threshold".

Need help on how to achieve this urgently.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There may be *display format* field defined in the auto number field.

Try creating auto number field without *display format*.

Like this:

[image]

Why you want to define the upper limit of the auto number?

I was not able to find setting to set upper limit for the field.

You can use validation rule or trigger.